# DataGridView binding error: Class does not exist in Namespace.Namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, namespaces

My error in my C# project:

```
Error   5   The type name 'Task' does not exist in the type 'MediaSnatch.MediaSnatch'   Y:\...\MediaSnatch_Home.Designer.cs 714 68  MediaSnatch
```

I am attempting to bind the class Task to a DataGridView in WinForms. Everything in the project is under the namespace MediaSnatch. For the life of me, I can not figure out why Visual Studios 2013 keeps adding the namespace to the beginning of the binding code in MediaSnatch_Home.Designer.cs:

```
this.taskBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(MediaSnatch.Task);
```

If I remove the namespace and change it to:

```
this.taskBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Task);
```

The error obviously goes away, since they are both in the same namespace and there is no reason to add it again... Until the next time I build, and Visual Studios changes it back to MediaSnatch.Tasks...

I have been searching for this forever, but it is fairly specific and namespace.namespace is not something commonly seen... anywhere.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on, and how to deal with this issue? Probably something simple I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did I read that right? Visual studio is changing your code on Builds?

Comment: You did, in MediaSnatch_Home.Designer.cs, it changes.

Comment: oh ok, I thought you meant it's physically changing the C# code above

Comment: Did you figure it out eventually?